# How do I hide the top status bar in my Firefox OS app?

Tags: firefox-os

I'm developing a FFOS app and want to hide the Time, battery indicator, etc bar at the top of my app. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the `"fullscreen": "true"` in the manifest.webapp file. Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Manifest

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Romin's answer, you can also use the full screen API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode